# Bash. Split text to array by delimiter

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

Can somebody help me out. I want to split TEXT(variable with \n) into array in bash.

Ok, I have some text-variable:

```
variable='13423exa*lkco3nr*sw
kjenve*kejnv'
```

I want to split it in array.
If variable did not have new line in it, I will do it by:

```
IFS='*' read -a array <<< "$variable"
```

I assumed the third element should be:

```
echo "${array[2]}"
>sw
>kjenve
```

But with new line it is not working. Please give me right direction.

Comment: `I want to split TEXT(variable with \n) into array in bash.` Are you sure you want this? Are you asking XY question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use readarray.

```
$ variable='13423exa*lkco3nr*sw
kjenve*kejnv'
$ readarray -d '*' -t arr < <(printf "%s" "$variable")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="13423exa" [1]="lkco3nr" [2]=$'sw\nkjenve' [3]="kejnv")
```

> mapfile: -d: invavlid option

Update bash, then use `readarray`.

If not, replace separator with zero byte and read it element by element with `read -d ''`.

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -d '' -r e || [[ -n "$e" ]]; do
     arr+=("$e")
done < <(printf "%s" "$variable" | tr '*' '\0');
declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="13423exa" [1]="lkco3nr" [2]=$'sw\nkjenve' [3]="kejnv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `readarray` command and use it like in the following example:

```sh
readarray -d ':' -t my_array <<< "a:b:c:d:"

for (( i = 0; i < ${#my_array[*]}; i++ )); do  
  echo "${my_array[i]}"  
done
```

Where the `-d` parameter defines the delimiter and `-t` ask to remove last delimiter.

Comment: mapfile: -d: invavlid option

Comment: Depends on what linux distribution you are using. `mapfile` is a synonim for `readarray`, try with this one. I update the post...

Answer (score 0):

Use a ending character different than new line

```
end=.
read -a array -d "$end" <<< "$v$end"
```

Of course this solution suppose there is at least one charecter not used in your input variable.